# Is is possible to get mobile numbers of Facebook friends using Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get mobile numbers of my friends using GRAPH APIs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither Graph http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

nor FQL https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/

seem to have phone numbers accessible.

Also, read the last paragraph of http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/447 as it explains that these have been disabled from the API.